# 12.04 can't connect to wired network/ crashes

Tags: networking, drivers, updates, offline

I've tried the server and desktop version of 12.04 and I get the same issues:

1. Entire system crashes while trying to install updates
2. Loses ability to connect to network (usually after a crash)

I currently have the desktop version installed but not updated. I have no network connection. I'd prefer to get the server version running. I've formatted 4 times now. When Ubuntu desktop crashes I get pink screen of death. When Ubuntu server crashes I lose signal to the monitor. Memtest86 has detected no issues with RAM or CPU.

I'm suspecting either:

1. Network driver not supporting Linux
2. Bad spots on the hard drive
3. Onboard vid card dying

I would like to try updating the network driver first as it does not require me to purchase anything. However, I'd have to do it offline, without another Ubuntu machine. I have the correct driver downloaded on a Windows 7 PC, but I don't know how to install it to the Ubuntu machine. I'm a novice, so Keryx was beyond me (I couldn't even get it running on my Windows 7 machine.)

Is there a way to write the network driver to a CD and have Ubuntu update from the CD?

Comment: I copied the driver to a USB and was able to run it with Ubuntu desktop simply by double clicking on it. I now have internet access and am currently installing updates. I feel foolish for not trying this sooner. For anyone having an issue with their network card, just go to your network card manufacturer's website and download the driver with a linux kernal.

Comment: I formatted and installed ubuntu server (because I'd rather use that than desktop.) I did some forum searching and got the command "cd /path/to/deb/files && dpkg -i *.deb" to update a driver from a USB stick. I get the message "no such file or directory". Can anyone help me with a command line that will update a driver from the USB stick?